# Are Warrants traded on normal stocks exchanges and secondary markets?

Tags: warrants

Hello I have a theoretical question. Are warrants traded as listed instruments on any exchange. And can the standard big stock exchanges like NYSE trade warrants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warrants are traded on exchanges though some have far more liquidity over the counter (i.e. by phone/email/Bloomberg). Typically, those warrants are issued in other currencies to attract international investors.

Warrants may be issued in an IPO as part of a greenshoe (option to issue more shares); however, they are most often issued with bonds. Issuing bonds with attached warrants allows the firm to avoid a large cash outlay to pay back the bond -- if their stock rises enough to encourage warrant holders to exercise.

Even when warrants are listed on an exchange and are more liquid there than OTC, take care: warrants tend to be illiquid wherever they trade. Bid-ask spreads can be very wide.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to common stock, IPOs can  contain warrants.  The IPO tends to trade initially as a unit but all three may trade initially as well (common, warrant, unit).  They can also be issued at a later date as a sweetener (see the APC/OXY merger).  They can be issued with other securities as wells (bonds).

In the case of equity warrants, they will trade on the market where the common trades.